# How to call a function from another header c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have most of this working I am struggling with syntax errors on the employee.h

here are all 3 of the headers

**Address.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Address
{
public:
    explicit Address();
    explicit Address(const string& city, const string& state,
        const string& street, const string& zip);
    const string& getCity() const;
    const string& getState() const;
    const string&  getStreet() const;
    const string&  getZip() const;
    void printAddress() const;
private:
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zip;
};

Address::Address() :
    city("Beverly Hills,"),
    state("CA,"),
    street("99999 Sunset Boulevard,"),
    zip("99999")
{ }

Address::Address(const string& city, const string& state,
    const string& street, const string& zip) :
    city(city), state(state), street(street), zip(zip)
{ }

const string& Address::getCity() const
{
    return city;
}
const string& Address::getState() const
{
    return state;
}
const string& Address::getStreet() const
{
    return street;
}
const string& Address::getZip() const
{
    return zip;
}
void Address::printAddress() const
{
    std::cout << street << city << state << zip << endl;
};
```

**Name.h**

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Name
{
public:
    explicit Name();
    explicit Name(const string& firstName, const string& middleName, const string& lastName);
    const string& getFirstLast() const;
    void printName() const;
private:
    string firstName;
    string middleName;
    string lastName;

    Name::Name() :
        firstName("John"),
        middleName("H."),
        lastName("Doe")
    {}
    Name::Name(const string& firstName, const string& middleName, const string& lastName) :
        firstName(firstName), lastName(lastName)
    { }
    const string& Name::getFirstLast() const
    {
        return name;
    }

    void Name::printName() const
    {
        std::cout << firstName << middleName << lastName << endl;


    }
};
```

**Employee.H**

This is where I am getting most of my errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Name.h"
#include "Address.h"
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
    explicit Employee();
    explicit Employee(const Name& name, const Address& address, const string& ssn);
    const string& getName() const;
    const string& getSSN() const;
    const string& getAddress() const;
    void printEmployee() const;
private:
    Name name;
    Address address;
    string ssn;
};
Employee::Employee() :
    name("John H. Doe"),
    address("99999 Sunset Boulevard", "Beverly Hills", "CA", "99999"),
    SSN("999-99-9999")
{}
Employee::Employee(const Name& name, const Address& address, const std::string& ssn) :
    name(name), address(address), ssn(ssn)
{ }

const string& Employee::getName() const
{
    return printName;
}

const string& Employee::getSSN() const
{
    return ssn;
}
const string& Employee::getAddress() const
{
    return address
}


void Employee::printEmployee() const
{
cout << Name.printName() << Address.printAddress() << ssn << std::endl;
}
```

Here are the instructions for the assignment

Name Header file (Name.h) will have:

A default constructor. Remember that the default constructor for Name has the following initial values: Name to "John H. Doe".

A constructor with 3 parameters: one for First name, one for Middle Name, and One for last Name.

3 private string instance variables for :First Name, Middle Name, and a last Name.

getFirstLast() function: it returns the first and middle name and last name in order

printName() function: it prints the first, middle, and last name.

Address Header File (Address.h) will have:

A default constructor. Remember that the default constructor for Address has the following initial values: Address to "99999 Sunset Boulevard" , "Beverly Hills", "CA", "99999"

4 private string instance variables for :Street, City, State, Zip

A constructor with 4 parameters: one for street, one for city, one for state, one for zip.

getCity(): it returns the City

getState(): It returns the State

getStreet(): It returns the street

getZip(): it returns the zip

printAddress(): it prints the Street, City, State, and Zip.

Employee Header File (Employee.h) will have:

3 private instance variables: One for Name (Use the Header Name from above), One for The Address (Use the Address Header from above), a string variable for the SSN.

a default constructor which initializes the SSN to "999-99-9999", Name to "John H. Doe", Address to "99999 Sunset Boulevard" , "Beverly Hills", "CA", "99999"

a constructor with 3 parameters: One for Name, one for Address, a string for SSN.

getName() function: it returns the Name of the Employee

getAddress() function : it returns the address of the Employee.

getSSN() function: it returns the SSN as a string

printEmployee() function:

print the name:   Make sure you use the printName() function from Name.h

print the address:  Make sure you use the printAddress() function from Address.h

prints the SSN.

Employee (Employee.cpp) class will have:

In the void main() function you would declare:

a Name n;

an Address A;

and an Employee e;

and print e using the printEmployee().

Also you need to declare:

A Name n1: Your Name

an Address a1: your own address

string ssn1: 987-65-4321

An employee e1 which has a name n1, and address A1, and ssn1.

Print e1 using printEmployee().

Comment: add Address as a friend class

Comment: ok and then what? create a function for printAddress?

Comment: Should be able to just call it directly as Address::printAddress().  Probably not the best solution tho, you might want to reconsider your design pattern.  This is a quick cheap fix.

Comment: `std::string Address;` Did you want a std::string or your `Address` class? With that said either way I don't like Address being the name of the variable when you have a class that is also named Address. And if you have an `Address` class why are you not using it with your `Employee` class?

Comment: @drescherjm its how the assignment was worded

Comment: This is the entire source of your problem. Having `Address` as a string shadows your `Address` class. In your `Employee` class instead of `std::string Address;` I would do `Address address;`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not quite meet the standards that StackOverflow expects. Your question in its current state will likely not get accepted. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

I tried to create a complete example for you.
You should put declarations in header *.h files.
Implementations go into the *.cpp files.

**Address.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Address
{
public:
    explicit Address();
    explicit Address(const std::string& city, const std::string& state,
        const std::string& street, const std::string& zip);
    const std::string& getCity() const;
    const std::string& getState() const;
    const std::string&  getStreet() const;
    const std::string&  getZip() const;
    void printAddress() const;
private:
    std::string street;
    std::string city;
    std::string state;
    std::string zip;
};
```

**Address.cpp**

```
#include "Address.h"
#include <iostream>

// Default Constructor
Address::Address() :
    city("Beverly Hills"),
    state("CA"),
    street("99999 Sunset Boulevard"),
    zip("99999")
{ }

Address::Address(const std::string& city, const std::string& state,
    const std::string& street, const std::string& zip) :
    city(city), state(state), street(street), zip(zip)
{ }

const std::string& Address::getCity() const
{
    return city;
}
const std::string& Address::getState() const
{
    return state;
}
const std::string& Address::getStreet() const
{
    return street;
}
const std::string& Address::getZip() const
{
    return zip;
}
void Address::printAddress() const
{
    // removed the endl here !
    std::cout << "Address: " << street << ", " << city << ", "
        << state << ", " << zip;
};
```

**Name.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Name
{
public:
    explicit Name(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName);
    void printName() const;
private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
};
```

**Name.cpp**

```
#include "Name.h"
#include <iostream>

Name::Name(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName) :
    firstName(firstName), lastName(lastName)
{ }

void Name::printName() const
{
    std::cout << "Name: " << lastName << ", " << firstName;
}
```

**Employee.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "Name.h"
#include "Address.h"

class Employee
{
public:
    explicit Employee(const Name& name, const Address& address, const std::string& ssn);
    void printEmployee() const;
private:
    Name name;
    Address address;
    std::string ssn;
};
```

**Employee.cpp**

```
#include "Employee.h"
#include <iostream>

Employee::Employee(const Name& name, const Address& address, const std::string& ssn) :
    name(name), address(address), ssn(ssn)
{ }

void Employee::printEmployee() const
{
    std::cout << "Employee: ";
    name.printName();
    std::cout << ", ";
    address.printAddress();
    std::cout << ", ssn: " << ssn << std::endl;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Employee.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Address address("Cologne", "NRW", "Domplatz 1", "D-50668");
    Name name("John", "Jones");

    Employee employee(name, address, "123-abc-456");
    employee.printEmployee();

    return 0;
}
```

That was fun! :-)

**EDIT:**

I think I need to add a little explanation:

If you want to use a function or method from one cpp file in another cpp file you should seperate declaration and implementation. Actually you should always do this. Put declaration in the *.h file and implementation in *.cpp file. In the cpp file where you want to use the function include the header file where the function is declared. Then compile all cpp files to object files. And then link all the objects files together.

For example look in Employee.cpp file. There I use the print method from the Address class. Now look at the includes of the Employee.cpp file. There you see I included Employee.h which in turn includes Address.h. Including is actually just inserting the content of one file in the other. So now we have included the **declaration** of the Address class and methods in the Employee cpp file so it can be called from there.

**Another Update**

I tested the code I posted yesterday. It works fine. The problem starts because you want to change the printEmployee() method like this:

```
void Employee::printEmployee() const
{
    cout << Name.printName() << Address.printAddress() << ssn << std::endl;
}
```

This will only work when the printName() and printAddress() methods do not print but rather return a string. In that case software developers often name the method `ToString()` or similiar. But we will leave the name as it is because we stick to the assignment of your professor.

You must change the declaration of the methods in the header files to return a string. And then you must also change the implementation in the cpp files to return a string. Here you go (not complete source code, only the changes) :

**Address.h**

```
class Address
{
public:
    // .....
    std::string& printAddress() const;
    // .....
};
```

**Address.cpp**

```
// Add this new include to the others at the top of the file:
#include <sstream>

// ......

std::string& Address::printAddress() const
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Address: " << street << ", " << city << ", "
        << state << ", " << zip;
    return ss.str();
}
```

**Name.h**

```
class Name
{
public:
    // .....
    std::string& printName() const;
    // .....
};
```

**Name.cpp**

```
// Add this new include to the others at the top of the file:
#include <sstream>

// ......

std::string& Name::printName() const
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Name: " << lastName << ", " << firstName;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Now you can use them in the Employee class like you wanted:

**Employee.cpp**

```
void Employee::printEmployee() const
{
    std::cout << Name.printName() << Address.printAddress() << ssn << std::endl;
}
```

**Final Edit**

After I read the details of the assignment you posted, I think my first solution was good. Your Professor clearly says the `printAddress()` and `printName()` methods should print not return a string. So maybe you should consider using the code from my first solution.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. The instructions had all the name address and employee stuff in 3 separate .h files and then they were tied together with an employee.cpp file that does something different.

Comment: Breaking things up like this is often the sane way way to do it. It ties in with the write little bits at a time philosophy I was ranting about in your last question. With `Address` isolated and on its own, it's really easy to test and verify `Address` on its own. Once you know `Address` works as required, you can write and test the other modules that rely on it. This takes longer to write, but it usually decimates the time required to debug and maintain.

Comment: the printEmployee still isnt working. it has the "." underlined and says expected an identifier

Comment: I posted all the code the way the teacher wanted it and the full instructions for the assignment if you get a chance to look at it. Honestly, I am debating dropping this class because this is way over my head.

Comment: Sorry I already went to sleep last night. I will help you now, it is easy, there is no need to quit.

Comment: Yeah I just feel like that I properly should have been told to take this after I have intro into c++ done. This is the first of 4 projects due Friday. The second one is easier for me and the 3rd I can do.

Comment: Yes you obviously need some C++ knowledge for that course. Hope you can get your assignments done until Friday. If you want to learn C++  there are some tutorials: https://www.learncpp.com/ . I like the next one, I think the course is free but you must pay if you want to take the exam afterwards: https://cppinstitute.org/self-enroll-courses

Comment: Yeah, my adviser kind of screwed me here. Sadly, I am suppose to graduate in Dec and I need these credit hours to graduate. I will check those out

Comment: Thank you though for this. It still has quite a few syntax errors but I will look at those in the morning or with my programming 1 teacher tomorrow.